# Nodemailer through a proxy

Tags: nodemailer

Can Nodemailer send mail through a proxy?

When I send mail without a proxy, it works perfectly but when I send mail through a proxy I have this error:

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET', sslError: undefined }
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
```

Comment: https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/125

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found a solution, i use mailgun to send mail through a proxy

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var api_key = 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var domain = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var data = {
    from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
    to: 'xxxx@xxxxx.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
};
...
 router.get('/api/postEmail', function (req, res) {
    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
...
```

Comment: Nodemailer should be able to send through proxy. You will need to setup the proxy settings in NPM though. For example: `npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080` Also ensure that the proxy settings on your computer are correct. Here's a link for a practical tutorial on Nodemailer - https://kounsel.me/category/coding-for-mbas/8tWJ4/coding-for-mbas-create-a-quick-dirty-mail-merge-utility-10-minutes

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Nodemailer can use proxy without a third party.**
To the transporter method, you need to add the 'proxy' property.

```
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.example.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    proxy: 'http://proxy-host:1234'
});
```

This should do. You can read more about it at: [Nodemailer Proxy Support](http://nodemailer.com/smtp/proxies/)

If needed, you can bypass proxy by setting the proxy for browser.
For example: In case of Google Chrome,

1. Go to Settings
2. Click on "Open proxy settings"
3. A dialog box opens, click on Lan Settings button.
4. Give your proxy value

Comment: Can you show me an example for authentication with proxy server?